# How will the "fb app support" on the upcoming facebook mobile app update work? What changes need to be made to fb apps to support it?

Tags: mobile, facebook-apps

As outlined here: http://www.cnbc.com/id/44726592
It looks like we'll be able to use FB apps using the Facebook mobile app.

Will applications need to be modified to support this?

Answer (score 0):

Anything at this point would just be speculation until there is an official annoucement from Facebook.  But yes there will probably need to be several changes to work on mobile devices that have smaller screens and don't support flash.